# Xamarin Forms Android - Fatal Signal 11 Error

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have implemented MediaElement on startup of application. In iOS works perfectly even user reopens app multiple time. In Android it crashes when app reopens 3-4 time and log below error. This issue is noticed on Google Pixel 5A and Redmi Note 8.
On Samsung M32 it's working fine.

> 01-07 10:13:54.149 F/libc    (16029): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code
> 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x6700726f746316 in tid 16072
> (RenderThread), pid 16029 (tpw.xx)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For this error message, we could not make sure what cause this issue. We need more details like code sample which could reproduce this issue.